# iPhone Store password incorrect

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, in-app-purchase

All of a sudden, I'm getting the above message when trying to do an In-App purchase with the App Store Sandbox.  How do I verify the user id and password for the sandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your question correctly, but there is no way to retrieve or change the password for the itunes test user.

If you have forgotten it just create a new test user.

And of course you can't access or verify the password on your own. The authentication process happens solely between apple and the input of your device.